# query that causes "MySQL server has gone away" error

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error:

```
Error Number: 2006
MySQL server has gone away
```

What exactly is wrong that causes such an error?
I tried a couple of suggestions like `max_allowed_packet` and some others discussed in the forums but none was a solution for my case.
Is there anything non-standard or even wrong with this query?

```
SELECT
    `st`.`stid`, 
    `st`.`shift`, 
    `start_date`, 
    `end_date`, 
    `off_date`, 
    `actual_off_date`, 
    `leave_type`, 
    `sd`.`off_day` 
FROM (`staff` as st) 
LEFT JOIN `staff_leave_period` as slp 
    ON `st`.`stid` = `slp`.`stid` 
    and start_date <= '2013-04-03' 
    and end_date >= '2013-04-03' 
LEFT JOIN `staff_off_dates` as sod 
    ON `st`.`stid` = `sod`.`stid` 
    and off_date = '2013-04-03' 
LEFT JOIN `staff_off_day` as sd 
    ON `st`.`stid` = `sd`.`stid` 
    and sd.off_day = 'Wed' 
JOIN `staff_leave_status` as sls 
    ON `sls`.`stid` = `st`.`stid` 
WHERE `st`.`stid` NOT IN (SELECT stid 
        FROM attendance 
        WHERE att_date = "2013-04-03"
```

Comment: It could be anything but it usually means that the database server has stopped responding - maybe there's an issue with the db, maybe your query is causing some extreme performance drain. You may want to analyze the query and see what it's doing. You have several joins and even a subquery in there.

Comment: In addition - where are you running the query from? MySQL command line? A php app? Etc...

Comment: That missing parenthese is a typo and not the problem!

Comment: The query is in a PHP app

Comment: What happens when you run the query directly in MySQL?

Comment: This query reads the every staff duty schedule and their today's duty status who must be present at work and who is in leave!

Comment: My question is how does this query behave when you run it directly in MySQL? I don't know what the dataset size is, but that many joins and a subquery feels inefficient to me. If this query consumes a ton of resources when running in MySQL directly, then that's your problem. If PHP is waiting too long for a query that's causing problems, you may see this type of error (the db stops responding...)

Comment: well sure the query triggers with clicking on form link that requires staff data to be viewed and modified and for sure it takes many of the database resources..! Do I have to do something about simplifying the query or any setting in some configuration files of mysql or PHP?

Comment: You're not really giving me any information to go off of. How long does the query take in MySQL? 0.05 seconds? 23 minutes? I need information. Simplifying the query is always smart but I have no idea if that's necessary for this problem.

Comment: Ok, the query is running for 70 seconds and then the error shows up! what does that mean?

Comment: If the error shows up when you're running this *directly in MySQL* then there's a solid problem. 70 seconds is a long time for a query but that's only the length of time before the server stops responding - how many records do you have in each table? At this point I can only say you need to focus on optimizing the table data and the query. Unless you've changed any default mysql settings that might kill long queries.

Comment: Ok thanks BotskoNet.. I will see how I can optimize the query!

Comment: Would you care to close the nested `SELECT` statement?